# How to know the class who is calling a method on inherited class?

Tags: php, inheritance

I want to know the name of class who is calling a method.

Ex:

```
class Mother{
  static function foo(){
    return "Who call me";
  }
}

class Son extends Mother{ }

class OtherSon extends Mother{ }


Son::foo();
>> Son

OtherSon::foo();
>> Other Son
```

How to do this?

Comment: Look into the [`__CLASS__` magic constant](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php)

Comment: Try using `get_class`

Comment: @ElefantPhace Author uses static class. "If get_class() is called with anything other than an object, an E_WARNING level error is raised."

Comment: __CLASS__ return the Mother class name.

Comment: @DeDee, you should test this code using `get_class`. No warnings are thrown. Also `get_class`, nor `__CLASS__` provide the expected results...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution using [`get_called_class()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-called-class.php):

```
class Mother{
  static function foo(){
    echo get_class(),PHP_EOL;
    echo __CLASS__,PHP_EOL;
    echo get_called_class(),PHP_EOL;
  }

}

class Son1 extends Mother {}
class Son2 extends Mother {}

Son1::foo();
Son2::foo();
```

returns:

```
Mother
Mother
Son1
Mother
Mother
Son2
```

So you can see `get_class` and `__CLASS__` both return `Mother`, but using `get_called_class()` will return the class that called the function!

Looks like you could also use [`static::class`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-called-class.php#115790) to return the same, if using php >= 5.5

Comment: Thank you, this was a problem that would make me do very 'hard coding'.